# Как можно изменить картинку?

Tags: javascript

Например, чтоб верхние края остались такими же, а нижние растянуть в разные стороны по шире?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартными средствами врятли это возможно. Как вариант использование `<canvas>.`

Comment: или же на php c помощью GD библиотеки и и неких хитрых махинаций

Answer (score 0):

Ипользовать можно две картинки размеры одной статичны(это верхняя), размеры дрогой зависят от размеров родителя,(допустим их можно обвернуть div или другим блочным элементом, а можно в качестве верхней использовать backgound-image, а нижняя `<img style="height:x%; width:y%;"/>`). Следует учесть, что размеры расчитываются в зависимости от ШИРИНЫ родителя. Если необходимо расчитывать размеры взависимости от ВЫСОТЫ родителя, тут можно использовать ява скрипт. Уместность применения скрипта в  данном случае зависит от контекста, но я не советую ренедерить страницу ява скритпом, уж очень это убого.